# Python classification technique naive bayes

Tags: python, classification

I am doing a research on classification techniques. I found a code online for Naive Bayes Classification in python. I have shared the code below. But I am getting errors in it. Please help in solving the errors. The software I am using is Anaconda with Python 3.6 in it. 
The code is as follows:

```
import csv

def loadCsv(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(open(filename))
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset


import random
def splitDataset(dataset, splitRatio):
    trainSize = int(len(dataset) * splitRatio)
    trainSet = []
    copy = list(dataset)
    while len(trainSet) < trainSize:
        index = random.randrange(len(copy))
        trainSet.append(copy.pop(index))
    return [trainSet, copy]


def separateByClass(dataset):
    separated = {}
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        vector = dataset[i]
        if (vector[-1] not in separated):
            separated[vector[-1]] = []
        separated[vector[-1]].append(vector)
    return separated


import math
def mean(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)/float(len(numbers))

def stdev(numbers):
    avg = mean(numbers)
    variance = sum([pow(x-avg,2) for x in numbers])/float(len(numbers)-1)
    return math.sqrt(variance)


def summarize(dataset):
    summaries = [(mean(attribute), stdev(attribute)) for attribute in zip(*dataset)]
    del summaries[-1]
    return summaries


def summarizeByClass(dataset):
    separated = separateByClass(dataset)
    summaries = {}
    for classValue, instances in separated.iteritems():
        summaries[classValue] = summarize(instances)
    return summaries


def calculateProbability(x, mean, stdev):
    exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x-mean,2)/(2*math.pow(stdev,2))))
    return (1 / (math.sqrt(2*math.pi) * stdev)) * exponent


def calculateClassProbabilities(summaries, inputVector):
    probabilities = {}
    for classValue, classSummaries in summaries.iteritems():
        probabilities[classValue] = 1
        for i in range(len(classSummaries)):
            mean, stdev = classSummaries[i]
            x = inputVector[i]
            probabilities[classValue] *= calculateProbability(x, mean, stdev)
    return probabilities


def predict(summaries, inputVector):
    probabilities = calculateClassProbabilities(summaries, inputVector)
    bestLabel, bestProb = None, -1
    for classValue, probability in probabilities.iteritems():
        if bestLabel is None or probability > bestProb:
            bestProb = probability
            bestLabel = classValue
    return bestLabel


def getPredictions(summaries, testSet):
    predictions = []
    for i in range(len(testSet)):
        result = predict(summaries, testSet[i])
        predictions.append(result)
    return predictions


def getAccuracy(testSet, predictions):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        if testSet[x][-1] == predictions[x]:
            correct += 1
    return (correct/float(len(testSet))) * 100.0


def main():
    splitRatio = 0.67
    filename = 'E:\iris.data.csv'
    dataset = loadCsv(filename)
    trainingSet, testSet = splitDataset(dataset, splitRatio)
    print('Split {0} rows into train = {1} and test = {2} rows'). format(len(dataset), len(trainingSet), len(testSet))
    summaries = summarizeByClass(trainingSet)
    predictions = getPredictions(summaries, testSet)
    accuracy = getAccuracy(testSet, predictions)
    print('Accuracy: {0}%').format(accuracy)

main()
```

And I am getting this as my traceback:

> runfile('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Naive .py', wdir='C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<ipython-input-11-c6b2508abccc>", line 1, in <module>
>       runfile('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Naive .py', wdir='C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop')
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>     File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Naive .py", line 109, in <module>
>       main()
>     File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Naive .py", line 101, in main
>       dataset = loadCsv(filename)
>     File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Naive .py", line 7, in loadCsv
>       dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
>     File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Naive .py", line 7, in <listcomp>
>       dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
>     ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Iris-setosa'

Please help me solve the problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like `dataset[i]` is _not_ a list of number-like strings, is it?

Comment: The first line of the dataset has column names. You want to exclude that when reading and converting that to float. Try changing `for i in range(len(dataset)):` to `for i in range(1,len(dataset)):`

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan The error is same no change in error

Comment: @DYZ No it is not

Comment: Then your list comprehension makes no sense.

Comment: @DYZ Wait the entire Dataset[i] is not number like strings. Half of it is. The rest are characters that is why the error specifies that "iris-setosa' is not getting converted.

Comment: So, don't convert them if they cannot be converted. Looks like you need to add a convertibility test to your list comprehension. Or, better, use `pandas.read_csv()`.